# Fill CardView with custom text and image Such as ListView

Tags: android

i want fill CardView with custom text and image such as listview, but i dont know :( 
Please see the sample picture to better understand what I mean
Simple Picture : [simple picture link](http://postimg.org/image/svw71z2z5/).
i use this link for CardView : [CardView Link](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html)

I am an amateur, please give me the source code

Comment: use cardslib it is more flexible and user friendly than native material cards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have pretty much all you need from the Android documentation. Just gonna give you a couple things that might not be obvious.

`CardView`is a child of `FrameLayout` so you basically want to build a `Frame Layout` with text and and image. If you are not familiar with `FrameLayout` what you need to do is put a `LinearLayout` (or any other that you find appropriate) inside the `FrameLayout` (or the `CardView` for this case) and add your other widgets inside.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    ... >
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <--This is where you add the text and image-->

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Try that and if you get stuck we can always help, but don't let the fact that you are new to Android stop you from doing things yourself, don't just ask for the code without trying first or you will always be an amateur

Comment: tnx dear #Carlos J, But I can do the design codes. I do not know how to call Java code, java codes for fill the imageView and TextView

Comment: Oh! So I guess I misunderstood the question. What do you have so far?

Comment: For example, my own card has TextView for title, ImageView for Logo and another TextView for sub info. ok? well i want fill its with java codes, such as listview

Comment: Ok, and have you written any Java code? Are you familiar with adapters?

Comment: No, I would not have written Java code, not the adapter code. You can write the code for me please?

Comment: The code for a ListView isn't complicated once you learn it but it can be a bit long so I won't write it all here. However I recommend you to follow [this tutorial](http://techlovejump.com/android-custom-listview-with-image-text-example/) that will explain all you need to do. From there it shouldn't be complicated to adapt the code for your project

Comment: Just follow the link on the previous comment. Click where it says "this tutorial" and it will take you to the page with the codes